# Cannot import name 'lemmatize' from 'gensim.utils' although I have installed Pattern

Tags: python, gensim

I try to use `lemmatize()` function from `gensim`. They said I have to install `pattern` also to use this function. I have already install both `gensim` and pattern but every time I try to import lemmatize from `gensim`, it keeps showing this error

I use `pip install gensim` and `pip install pattern` to install the libraries. My gensim version is 4.0.1 and pattern is 3.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\huynh\Desktop\machine_learning\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gensim.utils import lemmatize
ImportError: cannot import name 'lemmatize' from 'gensim.utils' (C:\Users\huynh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py)
```

I tried to look up documentation about this but all I could find is that I have to install `pattern` to be able to use it. Does anyone have an idea why I still don't have `lemmatize()`? Thank you

Comment: Can you tell us what command you used for the install ?

Comment: I install them using pip

so pip install gensim and pip install pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim only ever previously wrapped the lemmatization routines of another library (`Pattern`) – which was not a particularly modern or well-maintained option, so it was removed from Gensim-4.0.

Users can choose & apply their own lemmatization operations, if they think that's necessary, as a preprocessing step before applying Gensim's algorithms.

Some Python libraries offering lemmatization include:

- Pattern (Gensim's previously-included option, which can be used directly rather than through Gensim's old support): https://github.com/clips/pattern
- NLTK: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer
- UDPipe: https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/udpipe
- Spacy: https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer
- Stanza: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/

Answer (score 0):

For now, the best bet would be to use a `gensim` 3.x.x version as in the API documentation for version [4.0.0](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html), gensim.utils.lemmatize() is **not** listed, while it is listed for the 3.8.3 version [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_3.8.3/utils.html#gensim.utils.lemmatize).

Edit:

During further reading of the documentation, I found a tutorial which uses the `nltk` package for `lemmatize()` function. You might want to look at [this](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_lda.html#pre-process-and-vectorize-the-documents). Seems like they have dropped the `utils.lemmatize()`